# Correctly using atomic<T>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, atomic

I am currently struggling with writing lockless code for atomic variables for a C++11 thread pool class based on https://github.com/nbsdx/ThreadPool. Here is my modified class:

```cpp
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    explicit ThreadPool(int threadCount) :
        _jobsLeft(0),
        _bailout(false)
    {
        _threads = std::vector<std::thread>(threadCount);
        for (int index = 0; index < threadCount; ++index)
        {
            _threads[index] = std::move(std::thread([this]
                {
                    this->Task();
                }));
        }
    }

    void AddJob(std::function<void(void)> job)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
            _queue.emplace(job);
        }
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_jobsLeftMutex);
            ++_jobsLeft;
        }
        _jobAvailableVar.notify_one();
    }

    void JoinAll()
    {
        if (!_bailout)
        {
            _bailout = true;
            _jobAvailableVar.notify_all();
            for (auto& x : _threads)
            {
                if (x.joinable())
                {
                    x.join();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void WaitAll()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_jobsLeftMutex);
        if (_jobsLeft > 0)
        {
            _waitVar.wait(lock, [this]
                          {
                              return _jobsLeft == 0;
                          });
        }
    }

private:
    void Task()
    {
        while (!_bailout)
        {
            std::function<void(void)> job;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
                _jobAvailableVar.wait(lock, [this]
                                      {
                                          return _queue.size() > 0 || _bailout;
                                      });
                if (_bailout)
                {
                    return;
                }
                job = _queue.front();
                _queue.pop();
            }
            job();
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_jobsLeftMutex);
                --_jobsLeft;
            }
            _waitVar.notify_one();
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
    std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> _queue;
    int _jobsLeft;
    std::atomic<bool> _bailout;
    std::condition_variable _jobAvailableVar;
    std::condition_variable _waitVar;
    std::mutex _jobsLeftMutex;
    std::mutex _queueMutex;
};
```

I am puzzled about the following and would really appreciate any pointers:

- How to make usage of `_bailout` really atomic? I played around with `atomic_flag` but could not get it to work in this scenario.
- Is it possible to make `_jobsLeft` behave correctly using an `atomic<int>` without all those locks? I had an issue with the original thread pool where `WaitAll()` would not correctly return in rare cases. It works perfectly fine now but I feel like it wastes performance.

EDIT: Final version with normal locks is available here: https://github.com/stfx/ThreadPool2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the atomic methods: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

You should use the **load** method to atomically read the value. However, be aware that the following is not atomic.

```
if (!_bailout)
{
    _bailout = true;
```

There is a method to perform these comparison and value swaps. See **compare_exchange_weak** method. For the jobCount you can use atomic. The **++** and **--** are atomic.

However, be aware that the atomic is only a single method call, after the call the situation may change. You still need a synchronized queue and for that you need a lock. It does not need to be a standard OS lock, you can create a lock using atomic variable (using the **store** and **compare_exchange_weak** methods). See the following post: https://webkit.org/blog/6161/locking-in-webkit/

Comment: Thanks, very interesting to hear about spinlocks using `atomic<T>`. Btw just noticed that in `Task()` between `while` and `_jobAvailableVar.wait` it is possible that `_bailout` gets changed to `true` and `_jobAvailableVar.notify_all()` is being called which results in the new wait condition not being called after. Is that correct? In that case I probably need to move `_bailout` under `_queueMutex` anyway. `_jobsLeft` probably has the same issue due to `_waitVar` as you too pointed out which means that I probably don't get to use any `atomic<T>`. I would like to be told that I am wrong though.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I would recommend to rewrite the code as if you have the locks and all other synchronization primitives available. After that you can try to write your own - and they can use atomic. In the post, you can find all you need for that, they actually wrote their own spinlock and condition. You will not need anything more than that.